# 'Factors are not allowed' error when running bam() in mgcv() - R

Tags: r, mgcv

I have a dataset as follows:

```
 str(templates)

 tibble [2,179 x 8] (S3: grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  $ Speaker        : Factor w/ 5 levels "Alex","Lily",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ session_ordinal: num [1:2179] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 ...
  $ structure      : Factor w/ 32 levels "C","CCV","CCVC",..: 5 20 26 5 6 5 5 6 20 4 ...
  $ structurePC    : num [1:2179] 0.55 0.15 0.1 0.3636 0.0303 ...
  $ structure.ord  : Ord.factor w/ 32 levels "C"<"CCV"<"CCVC"<..: 5 20 26 5 6 5 5 6 20 4 ...
  - attr(*, "groups")= tibble [220 x 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
   ..$ Speaker        : chr [1:220] "Alex" "Alex" "Alex" "Alex" ...
   ..$ session_ordinal: num [1:220] 1 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 ...
   ..$ .rows          :List of 220
```

I'm attempting to run a GAMM model on the data using `bam()` in the `mgcv` package. I can run a simple model successfully:

```
 templates.gam.simple <- bam(structurePC ~ 
                       s(session_ordinal, k = 18) +
                       s(session_ordinal, Speaker, bs = "fs", m = 1, k = 5),
                    data=subset(templates, structurePC >= .1 & session_ordinal < 19), method="ML")
```

But as soon as I add additional factors (which I need to do in order to run my analyses) I start to get error messages. If I add another smooth (`s(Speaker, k = 5)`) to the model, as in:

```
 templates.gam.1 <- bam(structurePC ~ 
                            s(session_ordinal, k = 18) +
                            s(Speaker, k = 5) +
                            s(session_ordinal, Speaker, bs = "fs", m = 1, k = 5),
                       data=subset(templates, structurePC >= .1 & session_ordinal < 19), method="ML")
```

I get the error message:

```
 Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) : 
   NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
 In addition: Warning messages:
 1: In mean.default(xx) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
 2: In Ops.factor(xx, shift[i]) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

If I try to add an interaction to the initial model (`ti(session_ordinal, Speaker, k = c(18, 5)) +`):

```
 templates.gam.2 <- bam(structurePC ~ 
                       s(session_ordinal, k = 18) +
                       ti(session_ordinal, Speaker, k = c(18, 5)) +
                       s(session_ordinal, Speaker, bs = "fs", m = 1, k = 5),
                    data=subset(templates, structurePC >= .1 & session_ordinal < 19), method="ML")
```

I get:

```
 Error in quantile.default(xu, seq(0, 1, length = nk)) : 
   factors are not allowed
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't make a standard spline from a factor variable. When you use the `"fs"` basis, you pass a continuous variable (`x` say) *and* a factor variable (`f` say):

```r
s(x, f, bs = 'fs')
```

What this is doing is setting up splines in `x` for each level of `f` where the splines share the same smoothness penalty. These terms also include a random intercept for group means of `f`.

This is a special basis construction.

If you want to include random intercepts for other factor variables, then you need to use another special basis type, the random effect or `"re"` basis:

```r
s(Speaker, bs = 're')
```

I'm not sure what you mean by including the `ti()` term; the `"fs"` smooth is already an interaction between `session_ordinal` and `Speaker`. Looking at `session_ordinal` suggests this might not be a factor but you may have coded it via integers `1`,`2`,...,`n`? If you explain what model you want (what effects you want) I can suggest solutions...

...but in general you can include a factor in a tensor product smooth if you tell *mgcv* to use a random effect basis for the factor marginal term:

```r
te(x, f, bs = c('cr', 're'))
```

where `cr` means cubic regression spline and is the default basis for tensor products. You can do this with `t2()` and `ti()` too.

Comment: Thank you! It half worked: I changed the interaction to `ti(session_ordinal, Speaker, bs = c("cr", "re))` and it ran as expected. So it works for `ti()`, but when I added it to the `s()`, as in `s(session_ordinal, Speaker, bs = c("cr", "re"))` (and commented out the `ti()` row) I get the following message: `Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(xx) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In Ops.factor(xx, shift[i]) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors`

Comment: You can't have separate marginal bases in `s()`; `s()` allows 2d smooths only in the sense of isotropic smooths built from a single basis. So you can do `s(x, y, bs = 'tp')` or `s(x, y, bs = 'ds')` where the smooths are 2d basis rather than tensor products of marginal bases. Only for the specialist bases can you use `s()` with multiple covariates and the `"fs"` basis is one of those special bases. You can use `te()` or `t2()` or `ti()` for the construct you show but not `s()`. In fact, `t2(session_ordinal, speaker, bs = c("cr", "re"), full = TRUE)` should be equal to what you get with `"fs"`.